# Solve this 2nd order differential equation with a sin of the dependent variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$Ay’’+By’+ C\sin(y)=0$

I need help solving this I’m very rusty on my ODE and I do not remember having a sin function as the dependent variable within a equation like this, I need it for my research project on viscosity.A B and C are all constants and nonzero

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? If $B=0$ I think the exact solution can be expressed in terms of an elliptic integral. Often the small amplitude approximation $\sin(y)\approx y$ is used on such equations.

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have clarified but A B and C are all constants that I did not write out exactly what they are since it should be able to be solved without them, I am just not sure how to solve it with the dependent variable being in the sin function

Comment: I assumed so, but my guess is that even if $B\neq 0$ a solution in terms of elliptic integrals is still the best case. If you are happy with the approximation it becomes a constant coefficient second order and can be solved in terms of elementary functions.